# what is difference between normal pointer & self referential pointer in c language

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, self-reference

What is difference between different pointer allocation?

```
 struct node {
   char *name;
   struct node *itself;
 };
```

My question is -

Why it is important to `malloc` structure 
pointer variable `name` ? to point it something, 
while **self_referential** did not need to be dynamically allocated.

I mean both are `null pointer`...so why??

Comment: Please place the question in the actual post. That being said, you need to allocate (sometimes) for the `char *` because it is a C style string, and often should not be referring to an external string.

Comment: @owacoder: `char *` is **neither** a string, **nor** an _array_!

Comment: @Olaf - I know it is neither a string nor an array. (I didn't think I mentioned arrays in my comment. Or did I?) In this case, though, it is being used for a name, which is obviously a **string**.

Comment: @owacoder: you might know, but you forgot others - including OP - reading your comment do **not**. It is essential to be correct on a helper site. And not, it is not a string (type), but a `char array` which is **used** to **store** a C string. Yet it still is an array!

Comment: @Olaf - I see your point. I apologize for the confusion. I suppose I should have said "`name` is being used as a pointer to a series of consecutive characters which collectively store a name." That avoids the whole array/pointer/string terminology altogether. ;)

Comment: @owacoder: There is a name for "A cosecutive sequence of charcters": "array"...

Answer (score 2):

Both pointers will need to be set to *something*.  `name` must either be set to point to a string literal, an array of `char`, or a chunk of memory returned from `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc`.  `itself` will need to be set to another instance of `struct node`.  Whether you need to use dynamic allocation or not depends on what you're trying to do.

In a singly-linked list, the `itself` pointer will hold the address of another instance of `struct node`.  You can picture it as something like the following:

```
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+   
|   |   |--->|   |   |--->|   |   |--->|   |   |---0
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    
  |            |            |            |             
  |            |            |            |            
  V            V            V            V            
+---+        +---+        +---+        +---+          
|'f'|        |'b'|        |'b'|        |'b'|        
+---+        +---+        +---+        +---+
|'o'|        |'a'|        |'l'|        |'l'|
+---+        +---+        +---+        +---+
|'o'|        |'r'|        |'e'|        |'u'|
+---+        +---+        +---+        +---+
| 0 |        | 0 |        |'t'|        |'r'|
+---+        +---+        +---+        +---+
                          |'c'|        |'g'|
                          +---+        +---+
                          |'h'|        |'a'|
                          +---+        +---+
                          | 0 |        | 0 |
                          +---+        +---+
```

We have 4 instances of `struct node`.  The `name` members of four of them are pointing to strings, and the `itself` members of three of them are pointing to other instances of `struct node`.

Now, whether the strings or other node instances are dynamically allocated or not depends on your program.  You can allocate an array of `struct node` and have each element explicitly point to the next one in turn:

```
struct node nodes[N] = {{NULL, NULL}}; 

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
  nodes[i].itself = &node[i+1];
```

You can set each node to point to an already-existing array of `char` or a string literal:

```
char buffer[] = "foo";
node[i].name = buffer;
node[j].name = "blah";
```

Alternately, you can allocate everything dynamically:

```
/**
 * Adds a name to the head of a list
 */
void pushName( struct node **head, const char *name )
{
  struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof *newNode );
  if ( newNode )
  {
    newNode->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
    if ( newNode->name )
      strcpy( newNode->name, name );
    newNode->itself = *head;
    *head = newNode;
  }
}
...
struct node *list = NULL;
pushName( &list, "blurga" );
pushName( &list, "bletch" );
pushName( &list, "bar" );
pushName( &list, "foo" );
```

which gives us something like the diagram above.

It all depends on what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it is important to malloc structure pointer variable name ?

**1.** You can take input in it . Without allocating memory you will write to invalid location causing UB.

**2.** So that you can use it in functions like `strlen` , `strcpy` ,`strcat` (*exception being `strdup` but that will also allocate memory*). Otherwise , reason is same as above .

And it's not true that *memory allocation* is not required for `struct pointer`. You will need to do that while creating data structures without fixed size .

> I mean both are null pointer...so why??

But you should not dereference `null pointer` ,if you so you get segmentation fault (*if lucky*).